# How to increase ec2 instance root file system without EBS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to increase disk space of an instance without using EBS ? Root file system size is only showing 10 GB. Is there a way to create a bigger file system without EBS ?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.9G  3.3G  6.1G  35% /
tmpfs                 874M     0  874M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  874M   84K  874M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 874M     0  874M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb              335G   12G  307G   4% /mnt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the output, a much bigger partition is mounted at `/mnt`. You can move some of the things on the root filesystem there by either remounting it at the appropriate location or add symlinks. There is no other way to add more diskspace if you don't want to resort to EBS or a network filesystem.

Comment: I already use /mnt as you can see with symlink but it's bad (i think) ;) I thought there was another solution.